# Allocating and free object of structures

Tags: c, malloc

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I have the following code in my channel.h file

```
typedef struct channel_tag channel_t;

channel_t* open_channel(size_t channel_id);
void close_channel(channel_t *channel);
```

And in my channel.c file

```
#include "channel.h"

struct channel_tag {
    size_t channel_id;
};

channel_t* open_channel(size_t channel_id)
{
    channel_t *channel = malloc(sizeof *channel);

    if(channel == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    channel->channel_id = channel_id;
    printf("Channel [ %zu ] has been created\n", channel->channel_id);

    return channel;
}

void close_channel(channel_t *channel)
{
    printf("Channel [ %zu ] resources has been released\n", channel->channel_id);
    free(channel);
}
```

The problem is with my main.c file. Here I have a for loop that create 5 channel objects and allocates memory for them. However, if I wanted to free them later in my program, I am not sure how I can get a reference to them. This is only 5 I am testing with. But later it could be up to 300.

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    channel_t *channel = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        channel = open_channel(i);

        if(channel == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create channel [ %zu ]\n", i);
        }
    }

    /* Do some stuff with the channels and now free them before the program exists. 
       However, I need to loop and pass all of them, not just one */
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       close_channel(channel);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the channels in an array as you create them.  Make sure you can tell whether the `malloc`s worked or not at end of program (hence the `memset` in this code).

```
channel_t **channel = malloc(5 * sizeof(channel_t*));
memset(channel, 0, 5 * sizeof(channel_t*));

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    channel[i] = open_channel(i);

    if(channel[i] == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create channel [ %zu ]\n", i);
    }
}

/* Do some stuff with the channels and now free them before the program exists. 
   However, I need to loop and pass all of them, not just one */
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   if (channel[i] != NULL)  /* Handle case where some of the opens failed */
   {
     close_channel(channel[i]);
   }
}

free(channel);
```

Comment: `memset()` is not needed in this case: `channel[i]` is assigned to anyway before being tested. If you want to check the result of `malloc()`, you should do so before calling `memset()` on `channel`.

Comment: @Sjoerd - yes, that `memset` is useful if you don't continue looping after a failure. And the `malloc` result should be checked before using the memory.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you are rewriting the same channel over and over in the main. If you want 4 channels you obviously need 4 variables for storing them, or an array with 4 items.

`channel_t *channel[4]; for (...) channel[i] = open_channel(i);`

Oh and `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` will make 4 loops not 5.

Comment: Your right only 4 loops, that code was just for testing my theory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    channel_t** channels = malloc( 5 * sizeof( channel_t* ));

    if ( channels == NULL ) exit( 1 ); // error, etc.

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        channels[i] = open_channel( i );

        if ( channels[i] == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "Cannot create channel [ %d ]\n", i );
            break;
        }
    }

    // ... work, but only if i == 5

    for ( i--; i >= 0; i-- ) {
       close_channel( channels[i] );
    }

    free( channels );
    return 0;
}
```